# How should I cite emended laws?

Tags: citations, europe

I'm writing a document in which I must cite several laws and other regulations, but I have a doubt about citations. I endend in the following situation several times:

- There is law A, the main valid regulation about my subject
- Law A has later been emended from law B, which either changed already existing informations (some numbers, a specification...) or introduced or removed other ones (provisions, definitions, competence to authorities...)

I would like to know:

1. When referring to an emended or a later introduced element, should I cite law A or law B?
2. Is there any difference about the "size" of the emendation? For example, should I behave the same if law B increased a fine from 2000 $ to 2200 $ or introduced a completely new supervisory authority?

I'm particularly intrested on EU/European conventions. References to authoritative sources would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you get fined, which amount do you have to pay? the old or the new?

Comment: It is just the first example I could invent, but in general I refer to the new amount (or definition/rule/authority/aything else).

Comment: So you have just answered your question.

Comment: Something like "Law A (2000), amended by Law B (2007)" might possibly be an option. I'd go to the library and peruse a copy of *The Bluebook: A Uniform System of Citation*.